# Find the critical points for $F(x,y,z)=-x^{3}-y^{2}+2xy+x+2z$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

I started by taking the first order partial derivatives:

$F_{x}=-3x^{2}+2y + 1$

$F_{y}=-2y+2x $

$F_{z}=2 $

Now I would try to solve it for $F_{x}=F_{y}=F_{z}=0$ but $F_{z}=2$. How can I proceed or this means that $F$ doesn't have critical points?

Comment: I meant $+2z$ in the tittle. I just edited it.

Comment: I suspected it was a title typo! ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct that there are no critical points, because $F_z = 2 \neq 0$: there are no points $(x, y, z)$ at which the partial derivatives are simultaneously $0$.